# What does it mean to be a limit point of a set?

Tags: limits

I'm looking at an exercise where they talk about limit points of a set. But I somehow don't understand the notation they used for. Could someone explain me what it means to be a limit point of a set, and what it means if a set has no limit points?

Because they wrote that $a\in A$ is a limit point if for all neighbourhood $U_a$ of $a$ we have $U_a\cap A\setminus \{a\}=\emptyset$ is this correct?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Try thinking about the limit points of a set like $[0,1]$. Then try to understand the limit point of the set $\{0,1,2,...\}$ compared to $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$ all as subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. The first has $[0,1]$ as the set of limit points, the second has no limit points, while the third has $0$ as a limit point.

Comment: but is the definition above correct so?

Comment: That is the usual definition of a limit point. I'd preferably write $U$ instead of $U_a$.

Comment: do you mean with usual topology the metric one

Comment: It should be $U_a \cap A \setminus \{ a \} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @LewisMacRae thanks I thought that something doesn't work because with this definition $[0,1]$ wouldn't be itself the set of all limit points

Comment: I don't see the third example @AHappyMathematician gave. Why is $0$ a limit point? so how can I prove that for every nghd. So I mean yes for $n$ large enought it is intuitive that around $0$ we have enought points so that the intersection isn't empty because $1/n$ tends to zero but is this enought

Comment: Take an open neighbourhood $U$ of $0$. Then there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \subseteq U$. As you point out, for $n$ large we will have elements of the form $0 \neq 1/n \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ and hence $U$ also contains these points.

Comment: ah! makes sense thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want an intuition. For some point to be a limit point, it says that no matter how small an area about that point you construct there will be somebody infact uncountable number of points living with that specific point. That special point is deleted because obviously that point will be in that area so that is trivial and you remove it.

Comment: ah perfect thanks, and if $a\in A$ is no limit point then I can construct a neighbourhood such that the only element contained in the neighbourhood an $A$ is $a$?

Comment: Yes thats right.

Comment: And what does it mean if a set has no limit points? Can i then say that the only covering are the union of all points? or can I say that the set is Hausdorff?

Comment: No limit point means that every point lives in isolation.

Comment: but doesn't this mean that it is hausdorff? I mean I can find two distings open sets for distinct points

Comment: Yes the singletons are open in a discrete topology. So yes the space is Hausdorff.

Comment: Right with the discrete topology it makes sense.

But also if we don't take the discrete topology, then if $A$ has no limit points we can find for each $a,b\in A$ $a\neq b$ two neighbourhoods $U_a,U_b$ such that $U_a\cap A=\{a\}$ and $U_b\cap A=\{b\}$ right? but wouldn't this mean that $A$ is hausdorff then?

Comment: Yes it would mean.

Comment: ah so it doesn't depend on the topology i chose, if A has no limit points it is immediately hausdorff?